# Microsoft Graph Api Event list of group return Access Denied (Microsoft Teams Group)

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to get all events of the group but the API return me AccessDenied.

The user is owner of the group (I have add it via add admin API).

While getting authenticate token I am using grant_type password and scope Group.ReadWrite.All (my request also contain username , password,client_id,client_secret,resource parametr as on body).

but when I sent request to API I can not get list of events it returs access denied.

Even I tested it in microsoft graph explorer it also return Access denied error.

How should I fix this?.

Getting Token Api - [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/token)

The API for listing events
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{GROUP](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BGROUP) id}/calendar/events
Headers - Authorization Bearer {token}

The returned Error :

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
> "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
> } }

Comment: Could you check your bearer token here (https://jwt.ms/) and see if it has the necessary scope to call API?

Comment: @Shweta I already solved the problem, The issue was caused by a cache mechanism of Microsoft so, If I add an owner to the group via API I need to wait for invalidation of the cache :), Almost half-hour after adding the owner the API respond me. That is the issue.